# Is it ok to have many indexes in a mySql table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have some fields that have 4 different sorting options. And in different cases, fields are sorted or filtered by these 4 options and 2 dates and userid. Let's suppose that columns are these:

**Colums: id, info1, info2, option1, option2, option3, option4, date1,date2, userid**

So my question is this:

Is it ok to have 7 different indexes in a table (option1, option2, option3, option4, date1, date2, userid)? Does it have any influence on the performance of reading from and writing to database in large databases?

If Yes, What do you suggest as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes need updated when a table is INSERTed into or UPDATED.  Therefore, the more indexes, the slower these operations will be.

MySQL will typically only use one index per table per query.  If you have 4 different sorting options, it would usually make sense to have an index which covers each sorting option.

IIRC, You do not need an index on (a,b) and (a,b,c) because (a,b,c) covers both.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you perform a `CREATE`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` the index needs to be updated. Therefore, you should limit your indices based on the concentration of `SELECT` statements. You also need to have a basic understanding of how indices work, for example, if you have a composite index `(c1, c2)` and you run a query that only selects `c2`, it is useless. You may also want to look into creating a `VIEW` instead of an index.

Comment: Indexes update on read? Also, `MySQL` has terrible support for `VIEW`s, do not count on them helping performance. Even with that, you need indexes to query views with any degree of speed. The two are never interchangeable.

Comment: @Naltharial Thanks for catching that. I've had more exposure to MSSQL which has had great performance with views.

Answer (score 0):

'Indices and using them' concept is a TRADE-OFF. They can make you have a higher speed at searches but you have to pay the cost somewhere else. Many indices make DML commands to take much longer because indices should get updated at each UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT command. They want to serve you in searches and you have to pay the price instead. The more you have indices, the higher search speed you gain, and the higher UPDATE and INSERT times. They should be very wisely used and tuned.

You can see this cost-benefit in Normalization as well. You gain Normalization, a better analyzing power and a widely spread-ed data and you should pay for gathering them and joins.